How to continue this method of integrating sin(x)/x and possible relation to the Basel problem
(I'm leaving the photo in case I mistyped something)

$\int_0^\infty \frac{sin(x)}{x} dx$ $ = $ $\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x)}{x+2n\pi}dx$ $ = $ $\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{x+2n\pi}-\frac{1}{2\pi-x+2n\pi})dx$ $ = $
$\int_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)(\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{x+2n\pi}+\frac{1}{x-2n\pi}))dx$ $ = $ $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}2xsin(x)(\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-(2n\pi)^2})dx$
I'm trying to integrate $sin(x)/x$ from $0$ to $\infty$. I do that by first noticing that I can rewrite it as an integral from $0$ to $2 \pi$ and an infinite series that doesn't converge. My problem there is that I'm not sure how or even if I have to normalise the differential dx now that I'm using a shorter interval and an infinite divergent series. After that I simply do some algebraic stuff and I end up getting two different integrals. One is basically the same but only from $0$ to $\pi$ and that is where I thought that this method wasn't going to work unless I try one of the basic methods that already work with the original integral. What I thought was more interesting is how one could go about finding a different proof for the Basel problem that appears as part of the integral on the right.
BTW if you have problems with my handwriting please let me know.

Don't take pictures of the math problem. Write it out using mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

From your result to the answer, you can use the Herglotz trick (see here):
\begin{align*}
\pi\cot(\pi u) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{u+n} \\
\frac{\cot(x/2)}{4x} &= \frac1{2x^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x^2-(2\pi n)^2}\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}x dx &= \int_0^\pi \left[ \frac{\sin x}x + 2x\sin x  \left[\frac{\cot(x/2)}{4x} - \frac1{2x^2}\right]\right\}\\
&= \frac12\int_0^\pi  \sin x \cot(x/2) \\
&= \frac\pi2
\end{align*}

Is there a problem with normalising the differential at the beginning? That's what's making me doubt the rest

I would start from your third line: think of a single term in the sum being the integral of the region $\pi$ to the right and $\pi$ to the left.

Yeah I see that already if I understood what you meant. Oh wait of course because of the distributive property every element of the sum is multiplied by the differential so there is no need for normalisation.

Just out of curiosity what would be a standard way of solving the Basel problem from something like this?

Standard way? I don't know: a new question?
